# Mat Sort only sorting for certain rows/columns

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a mat table inside of mat tabs. I have columns in my table where the mat sort only sorts the first two rows. (dateOpened, dateClosed, orderNumber, invoiceNumber, purchaseOrderNumber) All of these columns are of type string. The other columns I have are sorting perfectly fine.

**table component.html**

```
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="caseNumber">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="medium"> {{ 'COLUMNS.caseNumber' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="medium">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.caseNumber' | translate }}: </span>
      <a class="hover-underline-animation" (click)="openCaseModal(row)">{{ row.caseNumber }}</a>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="dateOpened">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.dateOpened' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.dateOpened' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.dateCreated | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="caseTitle">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.caseTitle' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.caseTitle' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.caseTitle }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="functionalGroupName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.functionalGroupName' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.functionalGroupName' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.functionalGroup }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="accountName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.accountName' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.accountName' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.account }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="contactName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.contactName' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.contactName' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.primaryContact }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="statusReasonName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.statusReasonName' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.statusReasonName' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.statusReason }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <mat-header-cell class="large" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.description' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class="large" *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.description' | translate }}: </span>
      <span 
        class="description"
        matTooltip="{{ row.description }}"
        matTooltipClass="tooltip">
        {{ row.description }}
      </span>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="dateClosed">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.dateClosed' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.dateClosed' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.dateClosed | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="orderNumber">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.orderNumber' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <a *ngIf="row.originalOrder" [href]="createUrl('/order/', row.originalOrder)">{{ row.originalOrder }}</a>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="invoiceNumber">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.invoiceNumber' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <a *ngIf="row.originalOrder" [href]="createUrl('/invoice/', row.invoice)">{{ row.invoice }}</a>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="purchaseOrderNumber">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.purchaseOrderNumber' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <a *ngIf="row.originalOrder" [href]="createUrl('/po/', row.po)">{{ row.po }}</a>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="productSeriesName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.productSeriesName' | translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.productSeriesName' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.productSeriesName }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="rows"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: rows;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

**table component.ts**
setupTable() is called in ngOnChanges()

```
private sort: MatSort;

@ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
 this.sort = ms;
 this.setDataSourceAttributes();
}

setDataSourceAttributes() {
 this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
 this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
setUpTable(data) {
 this.loading = true;
 this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
 this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
 //logic to populate data tables from @Inputs vars
}
```

I am having a difficult time figuring out where the error is occurring with sorting on these specific 4 columns. Also that the sorting for these 4 columns are happening only for the first two rows while the other columns are filtering completely fine.

Any help/tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that my issues is in the matColumnDef and the data that that was being shown in the matCellDef. These needed to match. For example:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="dateOpened">
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.dateOpened' | 
   translate }} </mat-header-cell>
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.dateOpened' | translate }}: </span>
  {{ row.dateCreated | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
 </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

needs to be:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="dateCreated">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ 'COLUMNS.dateOpened' | 
     translate }} </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span class="mobile-label">{{ 'COLUMNS.dateOpened' | translate }}: </span>
      {{ row.dateCreated | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container
```

row.dateCreated now matches the matColumnDef and the bug is fixed.

**Side Note** I am still noticing the same behavior, where only the first two rows sort for columns, when all of the values are the same, EVEN with matching values for matColumnDef and matCellDef. So if anyone can shed light on that it would be much appreciated.